# Issues with ng-show using jQuery - Ajax load()

Tags: jquery, angular, ajax

I am using Angular 8, on page load, I am able to display the content based on the ng-show condition. While refreshing the div based on jQuery load() (replacing the div), the ng-show is not having the scope, so I am getting both the div. could someone please let me know how to address this issue?

```
<div ng-show="show">
Display the content
</div>

<div ng-show="dontshow">
Display dont show content
</div>
```

Comment: In angular 8 you use *ngIf, NOT ng-show

Comment: @Eliseo - It is working on the page refresh and not working when I dynamically doing OD manipulation only